# Does my MS SQL server meet attack?

Tags: sql-server

I use MS SQL Server 2017 Express Database in Windows 2016 server, I find the ERRORLOG file of MS SQL Server increase 600M per day.

The following content is from ERRORLOG file.

Does it mean that MS SQL Server 2017 Express Database meet attack ?

How can I fix the problems?

```
2019-12-22 03:36:09.34 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:09.34 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 14.253.239.25]
2019-12-22 03:36:09.34 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:09.34 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 59.127.222.102]
2019-12-22 03:36:09.42 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:09.42 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 104.238.63.33]
2019-12-22 03:36:09.70 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:09.70 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 14.253.239.25]
2019-12-22 03:36:09.70 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:09.70 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 59.127.222.102]
2019-12-22 03:36:09.74 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:09.74 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 104.238.63.33]
2019-12-22 03:36:10.06 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:10.06 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 59.127.222.102]
2019-12-22 03:36:10.06 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:10.06 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 104.238.63.33]
2019-12-22 03:36:10.06 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:10.06 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 14.253.239.25]
2019-12-22 03:36:10.39 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:10.39 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 104.238.63.33]
2019-12-22 03:36:10.41 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-12-22 03:36:10.41 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 14.253.239.25]
2019-12-22 03:36:10.42 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
```

Comment: How can I set only my IP such as 41.23.15.23 can connect to MS SQL server? How to create an inbound firewall rule to allow traffic only from my IP address to connect MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your server is being attacked, so immediately you need to make sure the sa account is disabled or has a really great password.

As far as blocking unwanted traffic, it's difficult for someone to tell you exactly what you need to do because there are hundreds of ways to accomplish this, and we don't know what would be the easiest way for you.  If there is a firewall between your server and the Internet, the firewall administrator should be able to block unwanted Internet traffic to this server quite easily.

If this is a system in a cloud provider (Azure, AWS, etc.), please check the provider's documentation on how to control network access.

If you don't have a network administrator that can address this, one quick solution is to set up a Windows Firewall rule to block the port SQL Server is listening on, which is most likely the default port 1433.  Then you need to create a rule to allow the one IP address that you want to be able to connect to the SQL Server.

In general, whether this is your home or a business, you need to get an Internet firewall set up so that inbound traffic is blocked unless you specifically allow it.  Further questions about how to do that should be posted in [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but I would recommend that you do some research first as there is a lot of information freely available on this topic.