# How can I create a Windows Firewall rule to allow only one IP address to connect MS SQL 2017 Express database in Windows 2016 server?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

I use MS SQL 2017 Express database in Windows 2016 server, now my MS SQL 2017 express server is being attacked.

I hope to set a Windows Firewall rule to allow only one IP address (such as 45.23.56.12) to connect MS SQL 2017 Express database, how can I do ?

Comment: It is not only SQL Server that gets attacked once you expose a host to the public internet. If this is a home or small office scenario, you probably have a hardware device with firewall and routing capabilities. Block all incoming traffic there and create a VPN for secure connectivity.

Answer (score 5):

Seems follow-up question of [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256116/does-my-ms-sql-server-meet-attack). However, following are the recommended actions in your case which could be quick release from the cause:

- Define static [custom port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxnUu.jpg) (other than 1433) for the SQL server service

  - Service restart required here, and the custom port number must be explicitly mentioned in connection string of application. i.e. (`DataSource = DatabaseServerIP,PortNumber`)
- Create new login with `sysadmin` permissions
- Disable the login `sa`

Also, consider applying [security benchmark recommendations](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enAE843AE843&ei=U6QAXoTjHq3KgwehqaOACQ&q=cis%20benchmark%20sql%20server%20&oq=cis%20benchmark%20sql%20server%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0l3j0i22i30l6.2105628.2105628..2105849...0.2..0.157.157.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.JGOBiLXOFuk&ved=0ahUKEwjE2Kzb1MvmAhUt5eAKHaHUCJAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) particularly the sections **Surface Area Reduction** and **Authentication and Authorization**.

Most importantly, do not let the database server expose to public network. Usually, the app server only exposing to public.

> Firewall rule to allow only one IP address (such as 45.23.56.12)

Start Windows firewall (you can use `wf.msc` from run command), select entry that related to SQL server from the **In-bond Rules** list (if not existed create **new rule**)

**To Allow specific IP**
Right click rule → Properties → Scope → from "Remote IP Address" section select **These IP Addresses** option and **Add** desired IP Addresses that only needs to be connect SQL Server

[image]

**To change port numbers**
Right click rule → Properties → Protocols and Ports → Enter the custom port (that SQL service listening on - configured in above steps) at Local port section.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Taken from:

[How to configure the windows firewall to allow only specific IP address to connect your ports](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2984/How-to-configure-the-Windows-Firewall-to-allow-only-specific-IP-Address-to-connect-your-ports.html).

---

Click on **Start >> Administrative tools >> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**.

Go to **Inbound Rule >> New Rule**

Click on **Custom** and the next page select **All Programs**.

You are at **Protocol & Ports wizard**.

select the protocol type to the **TCP**.

select the **Specific Port** option for the **Remote Port**, enter the port number (1433 by default) and click Next.

You will need to enter the **Remote IP Address** by which you want to connect your port.

Select **These IP Address** option for **Remote IP Address**.

Click on the **Add** Button and enter the **IP Address** and click Ok and Next.

Select **Allow the connection** option and click Next.

On the **Profile Page**, select all three options. **Domain, Private and Public**.

Click Next Button.

In the Last step, We need to provide the Name of this Rule.

Click on the Finish Button.

---

Do not forget to ensure that your MS SQL 2017 Express is **NOT** set for to use dynamic ports.

Comment: >>>enter the port number (1433 by default)<<< Why do you think that Express is listening on 1433 while it it is installed by default as NAMED instance and chooses its port dynamically?

Comment: @sepupic I don't know how does OP's server is set. Yes, by default, SQL Server Express generates a random port to listen on during install (and it listens for localhost only), and 1433 is a port used by its older brother. However setting up while using a dynamic port is inconvenient, especially when server is behind NAT. Uniformity has never hurt anyone...